# Unsupported operand when I tried to shift a byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read a `/proc/{pid}/pagemaps` file and get the page frame number and if is present in RAM.

The docs say that bits 0-54 are the page frame number and bit 63 is set if is present in RAM.

> 54-0
>   If the page is present in RAM (bit 63), then these bits provide the page
>   frame number, which can be used to index /proc/kpageflags and /proc/kpagecount.
>   If the page is present in swap (bit 62), then bits 4–0 give the swap type, and
>   bits 54–5 encode the swap offset.

I tried a basic shift-left operation:

```
with open(pagemap_file, "rb") as pmf:
    offset = (address / page_size) * 8
    pmf.seek(int(offset), 0)
    try:
        content = pmf.read(8)
        pfn = (content >> 6) & 3
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pfn = None
```

And I got: `unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'bytes' and 'int'`

Also:

```
pfn = (pmf.read(8) >> (6).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) & (3).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
```

But I got the same error.

How can I do this?

`pmf.read(8)` → `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xa1'`

Comment: `bytes` is a sequence of bytes, not a 64-bit integer. You will have to convert it. Maybe try `struct.unpack()`?

Comment: Use `int_val = int.from_bytes(content, byteorder='big')` to get an integer value to shift.